# Обращение к дружественной функции

Tags: c++, дружественная-функция

Можно ли вызвать `friend`-функцию из другой, обычной функции того же класса? Если да, то как?

Comment: Если допустить, что нельзя, тогда как вызвать дружественную фукнцию вообще?

Comment: Я имею в виду не из main функции, а например из функции класса.

Comment: да, можно. Она подчиняется тем же правилам вызова, что и "обычная функция". (просто имеет доступ к приватным полям дружественного класса).

Comment: Можешь накидать прототипы?

Comment: переформулируйте вопрос. Он не понятен.

Comment: Можете написать как правильно реализовать вызов дружественной функции из функции класса?

Comment: точно также, как и вызов обычной функции.

Comment: @KoVadim, переформулировал.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот такого эксперимента достаточно?

```
class Secret
{
private:
    void out() const { cout << "Secret\n"; }
    friend void top(const Secret& s);
};

void top(const Secret& s)
{
    s.out();
};

class Public
{
public:
    void secret()
    {
        Secret s;
        // s.out(); Не скомпилируется!
        top(s);
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Public p;
    p.secret();
}
```

Или так (дружественная одна из функций чужого класса, недоступная извне вообще):

```
class Public
{
public:
    void secret();
private:
    void stop();
};

class Secret
{
private:
    void out() const { cout << "Secret\n"; }
    friend void Public::stop();
};

void Public::secret()
{
    stop();
}
void Public::stop()
{
    Secret s;
    s.out();   // Работает
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Public p;
    p.secret();
}
```